# Ruby : How to take the next element of a array?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I got this tab :

```
 ["aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
 "15/87/2014r",
 "2453/NRc05",
 "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
 "Adaptée",
 "09/12/2013",
 "pub.pdf"]
```

And I only want `"xxxxxxxxxxxxx"` for example.

I found .next.element(s) but I got no idead of how to use it.. :/

Comment: Use `Array#[]` method..If the data index is fixed always,.. Like `data[3]`...

Comment: Do you actually want he "next" element, or simply extracting the 4th element (array index 3) ?

Comment: Why is `"xxxxxxxxxxxxx"` the "next" element?

Comment: Th array is not always this one and I don't want the 4th element, I really want the next. Like I use the first then I want the second then the third etc etc..

Comment: so you want the first element of the first array, the second element of the second array, etc?

Comment: @Difender could you define "next", please?

Comment: What do you mean by "tab"? How is `"xxxxxxxxxxxxx"`" related to the array you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Array#each`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-each) returns an [`Enumerator`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerator.html):

```
arr = [1, 2, 3]
enum = arr.each

enum.next
#=> 1

enum.next
#=> 2

enum.next
#=> 3

enum.next
#=> StopIteration: iteration reached an end
```

**Update**

Regarding your comment

> I have a array with some datas, and I wanted to save them in a hash with names like... `{Name : aaaaa, First Name : bbbbbb}` etc etc etc

Rather than calling `next` over and over again (I assume you are doing something like this):

```
data = ["John", "Doe"]
enum = data.each
hash = {}
hash[:first_name] = enum.next
hash[:last_name] = enum.next
# ...
```

You can combine two arrays with [`Array#zip`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-zip) and convert it to a hash using [`Array#to_h`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-to_h):

```
data = ["John", "Doe"]
keys = [:first_name, :last_name, :other]

keys.zip(data).to_h
#=> {:first_name=>"John", :last_name=>"Doe", :other=>nil}
```

Comment: My mouse is near the *up arrow*.. Let OP confirm first. :-)

Comment: @Difender Could you tell me what's your goal is.. I may give it a try. Still there is a *hope*.

Comment: @ArupRakshit : Stephan gave me what I want, thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Difender I still want to know.. Just tell me.. Where you find `.next.element(s)`...?

Comment: @Difender invoking enumerator methods explicitly is quite uncommon. What are you trying to do? There might be better ways.

Comment: @ArupRakshit : I have a array with some datas, and I wanted to save them in a hash with names like... {Name : aaaaa, First Name : bbbbbb} etc etc etc...

Comment: @Difender How this related to this answer.. ? :-)

Comment: @ArupRakshit looks like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)